# Grid/Box Header Menu Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, header, grid, dreamweaver

I'm an HTML/CSS beginner. I've made my first homepage without too much difficulty but I want to add some style to my header.

Could someone point me in the direction of a tutorial or basics of how to build a grid for my links or a starting point? I've been looking for one and typing up grid or table results in tutorials to create actual tables so I've not found anything appropriate to what I want to do yet.

From what I can gather if I can separate each list item and give it a border my idea is achievable but I'm struggling with positioning.

Comment: To get answers around here you must show that you have researched the topic by showing the code you've tried and where did you get that idea (link)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Dreamweaver supports it, but i'd wrap the menu in a `<div>` that uses the CSS `display: table-row` attribute. Then i'd wrap each menu item in a separate `<div>` that uses the CSS `display: table-cell` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of resources out there, I would reccommend checking around CSS Tricks and Site Point.

Here is one from [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-an-interactive-navigation-bar/)

Here is one from [CSSnewbie](http://www.cssnewbie.com/super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar/#.VPXEirB4r70)

Here is one from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/navigation-bar/)